# Mimic std::function template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, std, std-function

I'm want to mimic `std::function` template arguments but I don't know how it really works.
Consider this code for example:

```
std::function<int(int)> p;
```

How do I write class template that mimics this template parameter `<int(int)>` ?

```
template<typename ...>   <-- what should be here instead of `...`
MyClass
```

What I'm really trying to achieve is that I want to be able to `typedef <int(int)>` as function pointer  and I want it to be generic not only for `int (*func)(int)` functions.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
SomeSmartStruct<MyClass, int(int)>::MemFuncPointerType pMemFunc;
```

I want `MemFuncPointerType` to be of the following type:

```
int (__thiscall MyClass::* )(int)
```

And:

```
SomeSmartStruct<MyClass, int(int)>::FunctionPointer pFunc;
```

should be of this type:

```
int (__cdecl *)(int)
```

I'm using VS2010 so not all C++11 features are supported but it does implements `std::function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With variadic templates:

```
template <typename C, typename T>
struct make_member_function_pointer;

template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_member_function_pointer<C,R(Args...)>
{
    using type = R(C::*)(Args...);
};
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcce9cd4ea1ea881)

---

Without variadic templates:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };

template <typename C, typename T>
struct make_member_function_pointer;
template <typename C, typename R, typename Arg1>
struct make_member_function_pointer<C,R(Arg1)> : identity<R(C::*)(Arg1)> {};
template <typename C, typename R, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
struct make_member_function_pointer<C,R(Arg1,Arg2)> : identity<R(C::*)(Arg1,Arg2)> {};
template <typename C, typename R, typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Arg3>
struct make_member_function_pointer<C,R(Arg1,Arg2,Arg3)> : identity<R(C::*)(Arg1,Arg2,Arg3)> {};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a4e2b5a56ecfb99)

---

*Usage:*

```
template <typename T, typename F>
struct SomeSmartStruct
{
    typedef typename make_member_function_pointer<T,F>::type MemFuncPointerType;
    typedef F* FunctionPointer;
};
```

*Tests:*

```
struct MyClass
{
    int foo(int) {return 0;}
};
int bar(int) {return 0;}

int main()
{
    SomeSmartStruct<MyClass, int(int)>::MemFuncPointerType pMemFunc = &MyClass::foo;
    SomeSmartStruct<MyClass, int(int)>::FunctionPointer pFunc = &bar;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> *Can I somehow utilize the preprocessor to auto generate partial specializations of make_member_function_pointer? I've seen something similar is done using BOOST_PP_ITERATION but I don't know how it works.*

Sure:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };

template <typename C, typename T>
struct make_member_function_pointer;

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n)\
    template <typename C, typename R BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n) BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, typename Arg)>\
    struct make_member_function_pointer<C,R(BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, Arg))> : identity<R(C::*)(BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, Arg))> {};
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS (0, 20) // 20 is the limit of params
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
```

*Tests:*

```
int bar10(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int) {return 0;}

SomeSmartStruct<MyClass, int(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)>::FunctionPointer pFunc10 = &bar10;
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a0a52402f7017ad)

Comment: VS2010 does not support variadic templates, i was aiming for something like: template<typename T> struct MyStruct { typedef doSomethingWiht(T) funcPointer; }. I want to somehow capture and typdef function pointer from template parameter without overload for variable parameters number.

Comment: @AlejandroFreeman you want it to work only with function pointers? what does "*I want it to be generic not only for int (*func)(int) functions"* mean ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain myself well. I'm trying to achieve something like this `SomeSmartStruct<MyClass, int(int)>::MemFuncPointerType pMemFunc;` I want MemFuncPointerType to be of the following type `int (__thiscall MyClass::* )(int)`. `SomeSmartStruct<MyClass, int(int)>::FunctionPointer pFunc;` pFunc should be of this type `int (__cdecl *)(int)`. Can it be done ?

Comment: Thank you very much! If I want more than 3 params I need to create another make_member_function_pointer struct that can handle it ?

Comment: @AlejandroFreeman yes, just add some more partial specializations

Comment: Can I somehow utilize the preprocessor to auto generate partial specializations of `make_member_function_pointer`? I've seen something similar is done using `BOOST_PP_ITERATION` but I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 2):

`int(int)` is just a type so can be matched by `template <typename T>`.

Surely too generic:

```
template<typename T>
struct Pointer
{
    typedef T* type;
};
```

And then you may do

```
int foo(int i) {return i;}

int main() {
    Pointer<int(int)>::type f = &foo;
}
```

Comment: function type to be precise.